# Improve formatting/text recognition with Solr

Tags: php, solr, apache-tika

I'm wondering if there's any way to clean up the formatting of results provided by Solr (specifically the text field). Many documents are indexed fine, and when asked for highlights, Solr returns fairly legible results most of the time. Unfortunately, there are a not-insignificant number of results that seem to consist of a very poor quality text/highlights.

I've attached 3 images. They all come from the same document. Ignore the black bars, I had to redact some sensitive information before posting. The first is how the PDF appears normally. The second illustrates the problem with the highlights, returned when Solr is queried about this document. The third image is from the primary text field and also shows the text all chewed up. This is how it appears in the raw XML.

Is there anything that can be done, either during the indexing or during the querying to improve the text recognition or formatting?

As requested, here are the relevant bits of the schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

<fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

<fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntField"/>
<fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongField"/>
<fieldType name="pfloat" class="solr.FloatField"/>
<fieldType name="pdouble" class="solr.DoubleField"/>
<fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true"/>

<fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />

<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_en_splitting_tight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
       maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
    />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldtype name="phonetic" stored="false" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory" inject="false"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>

<fieldtype name="payloads" stored="false" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="float"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>

<fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_path" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />

<fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldSuffix="_d"/>

<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>

<fieldtype name="geohash" class="solr.GeoHashField"/>

<fieldType name="currency" class="solr.CurrencyField" precisionStep="8" defaultCurrency="USD" currencyConfig="currency.xml" />
```

```
<field name="weight" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="price"  type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="popularity" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<field name="store" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="links" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<field name="text_rev" type="text_general_rev" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<field name="manu_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

<field name="payloads" type="payloads" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_en"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

<dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false"/>

<dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_p"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

<dynamicField name="*_pi"  type="pint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_c"   type="currency" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

<dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />
```

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

<copyField source="cat" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="manu" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="features" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="includes" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="manu" dest="manu_exact"/>

<copyField source="price" dest="price_c"/>
```

Any help would be great!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your `schema.xml`? Especially the `fieldType` definitions of the fields you're searching in.

Comment: @lxg I've updated the post with most of the schema.xml.